# How to navigate between two API parameters in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm beginner of iOS app development, currently doing iOS & Swift Bootcamp on Udemy by Angela Yu. I have this app called H4X0R News, which shows [Hacker News](https://news.ycombinator.com/) all stories that are on the front/home page on the app by using its [API](http://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search?tags=front_page). By the end of a module the app works fine when `url` property from API json is not nil but there are certain cases when url equals nil. These are posts which instead has `story_text` property. So what I want here to adjust is add `story_text` to my code and use it to navigate between this and `url` parameter. Here's the code I've got:

#### ContentView.swift

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var networkManager = NetworkManager()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(networkManager.posts) { post in
                NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(url: post.url)) {
                    HStack {
                        Text(String(post.points))
                        Text(post.title)
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("H4X0R NEWS")
        }
        .onAppear {
            self.networkManager.fechData()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

#### WebView.swift

```
import Foundation
import WebKit
import SwiftUI

struct WebView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let  urlString: String?
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        return WKWebView()
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        if let safeString = urlString {
            if let url = URL(string: safeString) {
                let request = URLRequest(url: url)
                uiView.load(request)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### DetailView.swift

```
import SwiftUI

struct DetailView: View {
    
    let url: String?
    
    var body: some View {
        WebView(urlString: url)
    }
}

struct DetailView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        DetailView(url: "https://www.google.com/")
    }
}
```

#### NetworkManager.swift

```
import Foundation

class NetworkManager: ObservableObject {
    @Published var posts = [Post]()
    
    func fechData() {
        if let url = URL(string: "http://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search?tags=front_page") {
            let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
            let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
                if error == nil {
                    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                    if let safeData = data {
                        do {
                            let results = try decoder.decode(Results.self, from: safeData)
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                self.posts = results.hits
                            }
                        } catch {
                            print(error)
                        }
                        
                    }
                }
            }
            task.resume()
        }
    }
}
```

#### PostData.swift

```
import Foundation

struct Results: Decodable {
    let hits: [Post]
}
struct Post: Decodable, Identifiable {
    var id: String {
        return objectID
    }
    let objectID: String
    let points: Int
    let title: String
    let url: String?
}
```

So what I'm sure I need to add this `story_text` to `PostData` as `String?` and then make conditional statement in the `WebView.updateUIView()` function. Then update the code in other files. But like I said, I'm new in the programming world and I seek for help here for the first time since I've started the course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correct, you want to navigate to a simple text view if there is no URL for the Post?
So you can do it like this:

```
let text: String?
    
var body: some View {
     if let url = url {
        WebView(urlString: url)
     } else {
        Text(text ?? "-")
     }
}
```

Comment: It worked it way but story text has its all format text (like "<p>" for making point I guess, it takes text to next line on the site or "&#x2F" which creates slash). Thank you for answer

Comment: you can make a replacement for those special characters